# Android in date write today yesterday 2 days ago like that

Tags: android, jodatime

I need to print date like today,Yesterday,2 days ago like that for that i have done
I am getting date like : `String date1 = "Thu Nov 13 19:01:25 GMT+05:30 2014";`
calling like `str=get_userTime(date1);`

```
private String get_userTime(String usertime) {
        Date d = null;

        // String datee = "Thu Nov 13 19:01:25 GMT+05:30 2014";
        String datee = usertime;
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyy");

        try {
            d = inputFormat.parse(datee);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        System.out.println(outputFormat1.format(d));
         op = outputFormat1.format(d);
        op=formatToYesterdayOrToday(op);
        return op;

    }
```

and this is another function to get yesterday/today i have use this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292139/simplify-replacement-of-date-object-with-today-and-yesterday-strings-in-java)

```
public static String formatToYesterdayOrToday(String date) {
        date=op;
        DateTime dateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE hh:mma MMM d, yyyy")
                .parseDateTime(date);
        DateTime today = new DateTime();
        DateTime yesterday = today.minusDays(1);
        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mma");

        if (dateTime.toLocalDate().equals(today.toLocalDate())) {
            return "Today " + timeFormatter.print(dateTime);
        } else if (dateTime.toLocalDate().equals(yesterday.toLocalDate())) {
            return "Yesterday " + timeFormatter.print(dateTime);
        } else {
            return date;
        }
    }
```

But getting Error:

```
11-21 13:12:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(20654): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "11/21/2014"
11-21 13:12:10.626: E/AndroidRuntime(20654):    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:871)
```

On

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE hh:mma MMM d, yyyy")
                .parseDateTime(date); //In (formatToYesterdayOrToday())
```

I have used Joda-time.jar

Comment: here you have a trillion ways to do it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code: (delta is time in milliseconds)

```
public static String getDisplayableTime(long delta)
{       
     long difference=0;
     Long mDate = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();     

     if(mDate > delta)
     {
         difference= mDate - delta;     
         final long seconds = difference/1000;
         final long minutes = seconds/60;
         final long hours = minutes/60;
         final long days = hours/24;
         final long months = days/31;
         final long years = days/365;

        if (seconds < 0)
        {
          return "not yet";
        }
        else if (seconds < 60)
        {
          return seconds == 1 ? "one second ago" : seconds + " seconds ago";
        }
        else if (seconds < 120)
        {
          return "a minute ago";
        }
        else if (seconds < 2700) // 45 * 60
        {
          return minutes + " minutes ago";
        }
        else if (seconds < 5400) // 90 * 60
        {
          return "an hour ago";
        }
        else if (seconds < 86400) // 24 * 60 * 60
        {
          return hours + " hours ago";
        }
        else if (seconds < 172800) // 48 * 60 * 60
        {
          return "yesterday";
        }
        else if (seconds < 2592000) // 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
        {
          return days + " days ago";
        }
        else if (seconds < 31104000) // 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
        {

          return months <= 1 ? "one month ago" : days + " months ago";
        }
        else
        {

          return years <= 1 ? "one year ago" : years + " years ago";
        }
    }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: The code is here..: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12/3879470... Anyway please provide correct yesterday calculation. And 45 - 60 minutes will also be shown as an hour ago.

Answer (score 4):

for Android you can use the most simple way with [Joda-Time-Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) library:

```
Date yourTime = new Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(yourTime); //or simple DateTime.now()
final String result = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(getContext(), dateTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

This can now be easily achieved using the method in Android DateUtils as below.

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(feedItem.timeStamp)
```

You can get outputs like,

**1 hours ago,
Yesterday,
2 days ago**

Comment: I have used this, but I am getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1592863108000"

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
DateTime datetime = formatter.parseDateTime(time); // time = string time data

LocalDate localDate = new LocalDateTime(datetime).toLocalDate();
LocalDate localDateNow = new LocalDateTime().toLocalDate();

int diff = Days.daysBetween(localDate, localDateNow).getDays();
```

Then just use the diff to evaluate which day.

Answer (score 1):

In you DateTimeFormatter, it expects a Date in a certain format, i.e. `"EEE hh:mma MMM d, yyyy"`:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE hh:mma MMM d, yyyy")
            .parseDateTime(date);
```

But what you pass, is of format `"MM/dd/yyyy"`:

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
op = outputFormat1.format(d);
op = formatToYesterdayOrToday(op);
```

So, what you could do is to change your DateTimeFormatter to expect you initial format `"MM/dd/yyyy"`:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
            .parseDateTime(date);
```

This should solve the error that you get. I don't know if the whole thing in the end gives you what you want ("today", "yesterday", "2 days ago", ...).

Answer (score 1):

This should give the output you want.

> Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your date and then use `date.getTime()` in the following;

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();       
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(your time in long, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following the function to get RemainingTime but the format is almost same as you want. try this code and do changes as per your requirement.

```
/**
     * To convert expire time according to selected format(period) 
     * @param period
     * @return
     */
    public String getExpireDate(int period) {
        int days = 0, weeks = 0, hours = 0, mins = 0, secs = 0;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        Date systemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String myDate = sdf.format(systemDate);



        long millse = // your time in milliseconds
        if (millse < 0) {
            return activity.getResources().getString(R.string.already_expire);
        }
        long mills = Math.abs(millse);

        if (mills > 60480000) {
            weeks = (int) (mills / 604800000);
            mills = mills % 604800000;
            days = (int) (mills / 86400000);
            mills = mills % 86400000;
            hours = (int) (mills / 3600000);
            mills = mills % 3600000;
            mins = (int) (mills / 60000);
            mills = mills % 60000;
            secs = (int) (mills / 1000);
        } else if (mills > 86400000) {
            days = (int) (mills / 86400000);
            mills = mills % 86400000;
            hours = (int) (mills / 3600000);
            mills = mills % 3600000;
            mins = (int) (mills / 60000);
            mills = mills % 60000;
            secs = (int) (mills / 1000);
        } else if (mills > 3600000) {
            hours = (int) (mills / 3600000);
            mills = mills % 3600000;
            mins = (int) (mills / 60000);
            mills = mills % 60000;
            secs = (int) (mills / 1000);
        }
        String remainingTime = "";
        switch (period) {
        case SHORT_PERIOD:

            if (weeks > 0) {
                if (weeks == 1) {
                    remainingTime = weeks + " week";
                } else {
                    remainingTime = weeks + " weeks";
                }
            } else if (days > 0) {
                if (days == 1) {
                    remainingTime = days + " day";
                } else {
                    remainingTime = days + " days";
                }
            } else if (hours > 0) {
                if (hours == 1) {
                    remainingTime = hours + " hour";
                } else {
                    remainingTime = hours + " hours";
                }
            } else if (mins > 0) {
                if (mins == 1) {
                    remainingTime = mins + " minute";
                } else {
                    remainingTime = mins + " minutes";
                }
            } else {
                if (secs == 1) {
                    remainingTime = secs + " second";
                } else {
                    remainingTime = secs + " seconds";
                }

            }
            break;
        case DETAILED_PERIOD:
            if (weeks > 0) {
                remainingTime = (weeks * 7) + days + " days," + hours
                        + " hours," + mins + " minutes";// + secs + " secs";
            } else if (days > 0) {
                remainingTime = days + " days," + hours + " hours," + mins
                        + " minutes";// + secs + " seconds";
            } else if (hours > 0) {
                remainingTime = hours + " hours," + mins + " minutes";// + secs
                                                                        // +
                                                                        // " seconds";
            } else if (mins > 0) {
                remainingTime = mins + " minutes";// + secs + " seconds";
            }
            break;
        case EXACT_DATE_TIME:
            SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            try {
                remainingTime = target.format(sdf.parse(taskData
                        .getTask_expire_date()));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return remainingTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have data like this:

```
{"data":[{"id":"79tiyfjgdfg","sales_name":"Sengkuni","sales_branch":"Kingdom of Hastina","message":"Leader of Kurowo sent you a gold","timestamp":"2020-03-23 10:16:01"}]}
```

and call function like this:

```
holder.timestamp.setText(Utils.beautifyDate(context, notifications.get(position).getTimestamp(), "EEEE, MMMM d, YYYY"));
```

for another format you can check from https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat

Use this function below

```
public static String beautifyDate(Context context, String timestamp, String formatDate) {

    String beautifyFormat;

    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd H:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();

    try {
        date = fmt.parse(timestamp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String mYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
    String mMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("M", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
    String mDay = new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
    String mHour = new SimpleDateFormat("H", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
    String mMinutes = new SimpleDateFormat("mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    int years = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int months = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int days = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int hours = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (mYear.equals(String.valueOf(years)) && mMonth.equals(String.valueOf(months)) && mDay.equals(String.valueOf(days))) {
        Log.i("timestamp", "on same day");
        hours -= Integer.parseInt(mHour);

        beautifyFormat = hours > 1 ? hours + " " + context.getString(R.string.hours_ago): hours + " " + context.getString(R.string.hour_ago);

        if (hours == 0) {
            minutes -= Integer.parseInt(mMinutes);
            beautifyFormat = minutes > 1 ? minutes + " " + context.getString(R.string.minutes_ago): context.getString(R.string.moments_ago);
        }
    } else {
        days = now.get(Calendar.DATE) - Integer.parseInt(mDay);

        if (days == 1) {
            beautifyFormat = context.getString(R.string.tomorrow);
        } else {
            beautifyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(formatDate, Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
        }
    }

    return beautifyFormat;
}
```

simply adjust the time you want to be able to see results like today or tomorrow and others

Hope it is useful.