# How set date as today, 1 day, 2 day and etc

Tags: android, android-date

I have date array and i set data in my list.

```
holder.getDayReceipt().setText(receiptList.get(position).getCreatedDate().toString());
```

I need set date in this format:

```
Today  (16 June)
1 day  (15 June)
2 day  (14 June)
..............
```

How do it?

EDIT: You did not understand me

instead "16 June" i want Today
instead "15 June" i want 1 day
instead "14 June" i want 2 day

[image]

Comment: With bare hands. 1/ compute the offset 2/ some date formatting 3/ output

Comment: Search for apis related to java.util.Calendar. Use it according to your requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplify replacement of date object with "today" and "yesterday" strings in Java static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292139/simplify-replacement-of-date-object-with-today-and-yesterday-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the Joda library for time

for example:

```
public boolean isAfterPayDay(DateTime datetime) {
 if (datetime.getMonthOfYear() == 2) {
 // February is month 2!!
 return datetime.getDayOfMonth() > 26;
 }
 return datetime.getDayOfMonth() > 28;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this piece of code

```
public String getTimeDiff(long secondsTimeDiff)
{       
    long secondsInOneDay = 84600;
    int maxDaysAgo = 15;

    if ( secondsTimeDiff < secondsInOneDay)
    {
        return "today";
    }
    else if ( secondsTimeDiff < 2*secondsInOneDay)
    {
         return "1 day";
    }
    else if ( secondsTimeDiff < maxDaysAgo*secondsInOneDay)
    {
        int days = (int) (secondsTimeDiff / secondsInOneDay);
        return days + " day";
    }
    else
    {
        //use normal DateUtils logic here...
        return "....";
    }
}
```

Hope it would be helpful to you!!